# SQL Selecting from one table with WHERE clause on the joined tables

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have three tables. The TestOptionsTable contains a list of tests to be performed on an instrument.

The second table CreateScript, is a table to store scripts to run during testing. These scripts contain a selection of some of the tests stored in TestOptionsTable. The scripts are run and the tests appear on screen one by one.

The results of each test are entered on screen and stored in TestResultsTable. When saved, the column IsTestComplete, is marked with a 1 and has a datatype of BIT.

During a script being run, the user may be interrupted and some individual tests may not yet be carried out. When the tests resume I want to display a list of tests from a script that have yet to be completed. Essentially select data from TestOptions and CreateScript if there is no entry for that Test in the results Table. So far I have this but is not returning anything:

```
select TestType,TestName, Limits 
FROM CreateScriptTable 
inner join TestOptionsTable on CreateScriptTable.TestName = TestOptionsTable.TestName 
inner join TestResultsTable on CreateScriptTable.TestName = TestResultsTable.TestName
WHERE CreateScriptTable.InstrumentType= 'Instrument1' 
AND TestResultsTable.IsTestComplete <> 1
ORDER BY [Index] ASC, TestName
```

The idea is that data is returned if the IsTestComplete Column has not been set to true in the results table but no data is returned. Has anyone any ideas? Thanks!

**EDIT:**
Expected output is something like below. With test Name, category and limits of test

```
Full Test 1     Visual              10  12
test1           Visual              0.1 0.22
Test 34         Visual              121 2222
Flow Test       As Found            1   1.2
Test 2          As Found            1   1.1
Test 3          As Left             85  105
Test 6          As Left             95  103
```

Any incomplete tests will not be in the Test Results Table. I would like to select from CreateScript any tests that are not in the results table.

Comment: can you show us your table schema (sample data) and expected output please? You want to return data if the `TestResultsTable.IsTestComplete = 0`?

Comment: Please show some sample data. Maybe all tests are complete in your case ?

Comment: Any data in the results table will have isTestComplete = 1. Any tests that are incomplete will not be present at all in the Results Table. I want to return tests from the Script table which are not present in the Results Table. I thought I may be able to use TestResultsTable.IsTestComplete <> 1 rather than = 0 as there is no entry in the table for incomplete tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say

> Any tests that are incomplete will not be present at all in the
>   Results Table.

this means that you cannot use a INNER JOIN to relate the two first tables with the results.
Probably you should rewrite your query with a LEFT JOIN like this

```
select TestType,TestName, Limits 
FROM CreateScriptTable 
inner join TestOptionsTable on CreateScriptTable.TestName = TestOptionsTable.TestName 
left join TestResultsTable on CreateScriptTable.TestName = TestResultsTable.TestName
WHERE CreateScriptTable.InstrumentType= 'Instrument1' 
AND TestResultsTable.IsTestComplete IS NULL
ORDER BY [Index] ASC, TestName
```

Comment: I figured my joins were wrong so I had changed them before your suggestion and still no joy. Checking for null seemed to do the trick though. Thank you.

Comment: Well the LEFT JOIN will match/return all the rows from the CreateScriptTable also if there is no match on the TestResultsTable table, then the IS NULL will remove the rows that have a match (a test has been run against the name). Effectively this leaves only the the tests  not run